# Deleting azure service bus queue messages?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

I'm creating mssages using the nodejs client like so:

```
await sbClient
                    .createQueueClient('event')
                    .createSender()
                    .send({
                        scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc: date,
                        body: eventDetails
                    });
```

which is great and works, however the problem then becomes if I wanted to change the event details and the date how would I go about updating the message details?

My best guess is to make 'body' actually point to an event id of some sort that can be resolved, and if the vents date doesn't atch the scheduled enqueuetieutc date at time of excution it won't be acted on.

Comment: `date` is the date of the event which will be some time in future, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ability to update a Service Bus Message. When you schedule the message, you will [receive back a sequence number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/service-bus/sender?view=azure-node-latest#schedulemessage-date--sendablemessageinfo-). You can then use the sequence number to [cancel the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/service-bus/sender?view=azure-node-latest#cancelscheduledmessage-long-), and re-schedule a new message.

Comment: what's the difference between .send and .sendScheduledMessage?

Comment: Send sends the message immediately. It will then become visible to any receivers for processing. SendScheduledMessage will not make the message visible to any receivers until the scheduled date and time.

Comment: anyone can help me with nodejs plugin!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that if the message in SB queue is not "deleted" if you make a peek-lock. However any other type of recieving message will also delete the message in queue.

Also you cannot change the details (update message attributes / content) once its in the queue.